# задать уникальные номера экземплярам класса

Tags: c#

Есть класс с сообщениями для UI. Хотелось бы задать каждому сообщению уникальный номер, не прописывая его вручную в коде. Эти номера можно потом использовать в тестах. Пока что сделано вот так:

```
public class UserMessage
{
    private static int _index = 0;

    private UserMessage(string message)
    {
        this.Code = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _index);
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public int Code { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public static class Group1
    {
        public static readonly UserMessage msg1 = new UserMessage("msg1");
        // ...            
    }

    public static class Group2
    {
        public static readonly UserMessage msg2 = new UserMessage("msg2");
        // ...            
    }

}
```

Проблема в том, что порядок вызова статических конструкторов не определен, и если код выполняется на разных IIS серверах, сообщения могут получить разные коды. Можно ли гарантировать одинаковую нумерацию во время выполнения?

Конечная цель - получить одну и ту же нумерацию при каждом выполнении кода.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что уникальность, ***вероятно***, вам надо будет сохранить между разными версиями ПО, в т.ч. через 2 года, когда половина существующих сообщений будет выпилена/разделена/объединена и переименована, старые сообщения по прежнему должны будут иметь свои номера, а новые - не использовать старые.

Comment: @Kromster нет, это мне не важно. Я приведу один пример: некоторые сообщения являются подтверждениями, например "это действие приведет к Х, вы хотите продолжить?". Когда пользователь на UI жмет "Да", я отсылаю на сервер коды сообщений, которые он подтвердил. Во время серверных проверок сообщения с этими кодами не добавляются в список того, что нужно показать пользователю. Мне важно только что бы на разных серверах IIS получились одинаковые номера. Даже если они будут разные после каждого билда, это ничего не сломает.

Comment: @Zergatul, не сломает до тех пор, пока какой-нибудь пользователь не оставит станицу открытой на время обновления сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам не важен номер, то для уникальных меток идеально подходит GUID. Обычно в C# я делаю так

```
class MyClass
{

    Guid Id;

    public MyClass()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid UnicalId
    {
        get
        {
            return Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно, что бы номера были одинаковые при каждом выполнении кода.

Comment: "...Мне нужно, что бы номера были одинаковые при каждом выполнении кода..." - Этого не было в вопросе :). ИМХО, есть смысл его дополнить.

Comment: Гляньте в сторону составного идентификатора - уникальность места это GUID, одинаковость при повторном исполнении - Ваш метод

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Я не хочу привязываться к деталям внутренней реализации GUID, должно быть более элегантное решение.

Answer (score 0):

> Проблема в том, что порядок вызова статических конструкторов не
>   определен

Придется запихать создание всех кодов в один конструктор:

```
static class CodeHelper
{
    public static List<UserMessage> UserMessages { get; } = new List<UserMessage>();

    static CodeHelper()
    {
        UserMessages.Add(new UserMessage("msg1"));
        UserMessages.Add(new UserMessage("msg2"));
    }
}

public static class Group1
{
    public static readonly UserMessage msg1 = CodeHelper.UserMessages[0];
}

public static class Group2
{
    public static readonly UserMessage msg2 = CodeHelper.UserMessages[1];
}
```

С типом коллекции определитесь сами - может вам больше подойдет словарь или вообще вместо коллекции создать набор свойств только для чтения

---

Другой вариант, позволяющий не использовать индексы или имена элементов - создать все элементы последовательно в одном методе. В этом случае, конечно, придется отказаться от `readonly`:

```
public static void Init()
{
    Group1.msg1 = new UserMessage("msg1");
    Group2.msg2 = new UserMessage("msg2");
}

public static class Group1
{
    public static UserMessage msg1;
}

public static class Group2
{
    public static UserMessage msg2;
}
```

При инициализации приложения нужно будет вызвать `UserMessage.Init();`

Comment: Если подумать, такой вариант равносилен ручной нумерации. Можно было просто задавать номер через параметр в конструкторе, вместо индекса в коллекции. Вероятность допустить ошибку такая же.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1. Не использовать статические конструкторы (инлайн инициализацию, что - то же самое в контексте Вашего вопроса) для создания объектов:

```
private static UserMessage fmsg1;
public static readonly UserMessage msg1 
{ 
  get 
  { 
    if (fmsg1 == null)
      fmsg1= new UserMessage("msg1");
    return fmsg1;
  }
}
```

Вариант 2. Использовать статические конструктoры, но самому определить порядок их вызова:

```
public static class Group1
{
  public static readonly UserMessage msg1 = new UserMessage("msg1");;
  public static void Register() {}
}

public static class Group2
{
  public static readonly UserMessage msg2 = new UserMessage("msg2");
  public static void Register() {}
}


protected void Application_Start()
{
  Group1.Register();
  Group2.Register();
  ...
}
```

Comment: @АндрейNOP Пардон, не оттуда скопировал кусок - кофе еще не допил, то есть не до конца проснулся.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как гарантируется порядок создания в первом варианте

Comment: Во втором варианте, думаю, нет гарантий, что статические конструкторы не выполнятся до вызова `Group1.Register();`

Comment: Да, в первом случае порядок не гарантируется...

Answer (score 0):

Если предполагается, что имена полей с событиями будут разными, можно использовать их в качестве кода (придётся его поменять на строковый): [tio.run](https://tio.run/##lZE/b4MwEMV3f4pTJpBaJFhRJ4YuTYZGVYeqg2NO1JL/IJ@hiiI@O8VAA2maSh3v7uf33p0F3QvrsO8bkqaC/ZE86pytq@S5MV5qTAqra6nQ7dG1UiDljNXNQUkBQnEieCF0WyTiFbITA6idbLnHdT8i74Kynso7eCu4UmGsD@h2XOM7zIiwJcIDmEapeBALggD@Q9KQY5wEIF@6s8MwmMXDrGMhxxRy1h1fn6BCn58TUii6K/Rb8nd6jXN/vsKjs02dnhNfIg55aY06rm8Cmqo0bIqfF6faDH1IN/H1Hj/dsn@6ZbfcspturZUlbLk00fIZhTVkFSavTnp8kgajafckLDT@Upz/BWYBzBawY13ffwE)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class UserMessage
{
  private UserMessage(string message, [CallerMemberName] string code = null)
  {
    this.Code = code;
    this.Message = message;
  }

  public string Code { get; private set; }
  public string Message { get; private set; }

  public static class Group1
  {
    public static readonly UserMessage msg1 = new UserMessage("msg 1");
  }

  public static class Group2
  {
    public static readonly UserMessage msg2 = new UserMessage("msg 2");
  }

  public static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(Group1.msg1.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(Group2.msg2.Code);
  }
}
```

```
msg1
msg2
```